# Register an Autofac module and return IServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I have the API configuration splitted into two projects (the principal and the secondary). In the principal Startup.cs, I configure Autofac, and in the secondary, I use the IServiceCollection returned by the principal.

For register an Autofac module, I should code:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    var container = new ContainerBuilder();
    container.Populate(services);
    container.RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule());
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build()); // Instead of 'return services;'
}
```

And if you see the returned type, it's IServiceProvider instead of IServiceCollection. How can I register a module, but return IServiceCollection? I have tried to cast from IServiceProvider to IServiceCollection, but an exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like to me your autofac setup is incorrect. Please have a look at what ive outlined below.

Program.cs

```
 public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureServices(collection => collection.AddAutofac()) //Important
            .Build();
```

Startup.cs

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
     services.AddMvc();
    }
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
      container.RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule());
    }
```

Because of the `.ConfigureServices(collection => collection.AddAutofac())` line in your program cs the `ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)` is automatically called (put a breakpoint :) ) in your startup class and the container is built and registered within your current api, if you replicate this across to your secondary api you wont have to worry about passing your service collection around from one api to another and each one will register its own dependencies.

Also ensure you have `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection` nuget package installed!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, your code is correct. You have to create autofac `Module` in your second project, and then register it in the first project by adding following code to the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
container.RegisterModule<YourModuleInSecondProject>();
```

Please find a good article about autofac basics [here](http://jakubskoczen.pl/2017/03/24/en-how-add-autofac-container-asp-net-core-app/).

Also please mind that dotnet core comes with built-in dependency injector, you can find a simple tutorial [here](https://stackify.com/net-core-dependency-injection/).

Comment: The code is from the official documentation. The second project uses the IServiceCollection returned by the principal project, and the code return IServiceProvider instead of IServiceCollection. I need to return IServiceCollection from the ConfigureServices method.